# jquery replace overwrite the content

Tags: jquery, string, select, replace

Briefly, I have multiple selects on multiple rows, and when I want to change something from a select, on change, I want to append the values to another row.

So basically, If I select something from row 1, if is the first time when I select, append the values to the new table, if I change my mind and I want to change something else, just update the values.
And so on, with every row selected.

This is my code and what I have done so far, but I am stucked and I don't know how to solve it.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="cell1">1</td>
  <td class="cell2">111</td>
  <td class="cell3">2018-12-22</td>
  <td class="cell4">Apples</td>
  <td class="liga">France</td>
  <td>
    <select class="cell-select">
      <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
      <option value="1.4">A</option>
      <option value="2.3">B</option>
      <option value="3.2">C</option>
      <option value="1.5">D</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <td class="cell1">2</td>
    <td class="cell2">222</td>
    <td class="cell3">2018-12-23</td>
    <td class="cell4">Oranges</td>
    <td class="liga">Austria</td>
    <td>
      <select class="cell-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
        <option value="1.1">X</option>
        <option value="4.3">Y</option>
        <option value="2.2">Z</option>
        <option value="3.5">W</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>  
<tr>
    <td class="cell1">3</td>
    <td class="cell2">222</td>
    <td class="cell3">2018-12-24</td>
    <td class="cell4">Bananas</td>
    <td class="liga">Germany</td>
    <td>
      <select class="cell-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
        <option value="2.1">L</option>
        <option value="3.5">M</option>
        <option value="4.1">N</option>
        <option value="2.2">Q</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>   
</table>

<table class="result">
    <tr>
        <td class="newcell1"></td>
        <td class="newcell2"></td>
        <td class="newcell3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The jquery code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $( "select.cell-select" ).change(function() {
        var cell2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell2').text();
        var cell4 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell4').text();
        var cellSelect = this.value;

        var newcell1 = $('.newcell1').empty().append(cell2);
        var newcell2 = $('.newcell2').empty().append(cell4);
        var newcell3 = $('.newcell3').empty().append(cellSelect);

$('.result').append('<tr><td class="newcell1">'+cell2+'</td><td class="newcell2">'+cell4+'</td><td class="newcell3">'+cellSelect+'</td></tr>');
        });
});
```

And the playground: https://codepen.io/tudor-taranu/pen/qLrGWY
One more question, there is a way to sort the OPTION values Ascending ?
Many thanks

Comment: because your are emptying it? `var newcell1 = $('.newcell1').empty().append(cell2);`

Comment: yes, If I change the value from row 1, first I want to delete it, and after add the new value. But is not adding properly the rows

Comment: Can you add expected output to your question?

Comment: I have addded the desired output on codepen.
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="newcell1">111</td>
  <td class="newcell2">Apples</td>
  <td class="newcell3">1.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="newcell1">222</td>
  <td class="newcell2">Oranges</td>
  <td class="newcell3">4.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="newcell1">333</td>
  <td class="newcell2">Bananas</td>
  <td class="newcell3">4.1</td>
</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below adds a `.change` event listener to each of the `select` in with the class `.cell-select`. It then gathers the name of the product, ID (which I've added) and also the chosen option from the select.

It then adds a new row the first timea select is changed, or edits the existing row if it does exist. I've added an `id` to each of the original table rows to make this possible, you could use another unique value if you wanted, but it's probably best to add a unique identifier to each row in the original table.

I've also added a check to see if the user returns to the default 'Select one', if the value of the choice is `=""` then any previous choice is deleted from the results table and the function exits early.

Let me know if that isn't what you were hoping for.

```js
// Add change event to each select
$(".cell-select").change(function() {

  // Get ID, name and chosen option
  productID = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
  productName = $(this).closest("tr").find(".cell4").text();
  chosenOption = $(this).find(":selected").text();
  chosenValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();

  // Check if 'Select one' has been chosen, remove any previous selection and exit function early
  if (chosenValue == "") {
    $("#" + productID + "-result").remove();
    return;
  }

  // Check if a results row exists
  if ($("#" + productID + "-result").length == 0) {

    // Create row if it does not exist
    $("table.result").append("<tr id='" + productID + "-result'><td>" + productName + "</td><td class='choice'>Choice: " + chosenOption + "</td></tr>");

  } else {

    // Update choice if it does exist
    $("#" + productID + "-result .choice").html("Choice: " + chosenOption);

  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="product1">
    <td class="cell1">1</td>
    <td class="cell2">111</td>
    <td class="cell3">2018-12-22</td>
    <td class="cell4">Apples</td>
    <td class="liga">France</td>
    <td>
      <select class="cell-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
        <option value="1.4">A</option>
        <option value="2.3">B</option>
        <option value="3.2">C</option>
        <option value="1.5">D</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="product2">
    <td class="cell1">2</td>
    <td class="cell2">222</td>
    <td class="cell3">2018-12-23</td>
    <td class="cell4">Oranges</td>
    <td class="liga">Austria</td>
    <td>
      <select class="cell-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
        <option value="1.1">X</option>
        <option value="4.3">Y</option>
        <option value="2.2">Z</option>
        <option value="3.5">W</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="product3">
    <td class="cell1">3</td>
    <td class="cell2">222</td>
    <td class="cell3">2018-12-24</td>
    <td class="cell4">Bananas</td>
    <td class="liga">Germany</td>
    <td>
      <select class="cell-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
        <option value="2.1">L</option>
        <option value="3.5">M</option>
        <option value="4.1">N</option>
        <option value="2.2">Q</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="result">
  <tr>
    <td class="newcell1"></td>
    <td class="newcell2"></td>
    <td class="newcell3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution works great, thanks !

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Well your code looks good but you have to understand the pattern you are asking when appending, here is what you can do.

Few things you need to consider:

- You do not need result append line
- I added `data-select` over it apply your code.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
 $( "select.cell-select" ).change(function() {
    var classToCheck = $(this).attr('data-select')
  var cell2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell2').text();
  var cell4 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cell4').text();
  var cellSelect = this.value;
   
  var newcell1 = $('.' + classToCheck).find('td').eq(0).empty().append(cell2);
  var newcell2 = $('.' + classToCheck).find('td').eq(1).empty().append(cell4);
  var newcell3 = $('.' + classToCheck).find('td').eq(2).empty().append(cellSelect);

//$('.result').append('<tr><td class="newcell1">'+cell2+'</td><td class="newcell2">'+cell4+'</td><td class="newcell3">'+cellSelect+'</td></tr>');
  });
});
```

```css
table{float:left}
td{border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="cell1">1</td>
  <td class="cell2">111</td>
  <td class="cell3">2018-12-22</td>
  <td class="cell4">Apples</td>
  <td class="liga">France</td>
  <td>
    <select  data-select="newcell1" class="cell-select">
      <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
      <option value="1.4">A</option>
      <option value="2.3">B</option>
      <option value="3.2">C</option>
      <option value="1.5">D</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <td class="cell1">2</td>
    <td class="cell2">222</td>
    <td class="cell3">2018-12-23</td>
    <td class="cell4">Oranges</td>
    <td class="liga">Austria</td>
    <td>
      <select  data-select="newcell2" class="cell-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
        <option value="1.1">X</option>
        <option value="4.3">Y</option>
        <option value="2.2">Z</option>
        <option value="3.5">W</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>  
<tr>
    <td class="cell1">3</td>
    <td class="cell2">333</td>
    <td class="cell3">2018-12-24</td>
    <td class="cell4">Bananas</td>
    <td class="liga">Germany</td>
    <td>
      <select  data-select="newcell3"  class="cell-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select one</option>
        <option value="2.1">L</option>
        <option value="3.5">M</option>
        <option value="4.1">N</option>
        <option value="2.2">Q</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>   
</table>

<table class="result">
 <tr class="newcell1">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr class="newcell2">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr class="newcell3">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
  <td class="">111</td>
  <td class="">Apples</td>
  <td class="">1.4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="">222</td>
  <td class="">Oranges</td>
  <td class="">4.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="">333</td>
  <td class="">Bananas</td>
  <td class="">4.1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```